# Complete Riemannian manifold $M,$ $C$ closed subset of $M.$ Then for $p\in M$ there is $p^{'}\in C$ that is as close to $p$

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

I'm trying to prove the next:

> If $C$ is a closed subset of a complete Riemannian manifold $M,$ then for each $p\in M,$ there is a point $p^{'}\in C$ that is as close to $p$ as possible.

So I'd like to prove that there is $p^{'}\in C$ such that $d(p,p^{'})=d(p,C):=\displaystyle\inf_{q\in C}d(p,q).$

I'm stuck proving this. If $C$ were bounded, the Hopf-Rinow theorem would imply the compactness of $C$ and we can get such point utilizing the sequence criteria of compactness.

However, $C$ only is closed. Then, since $(M,d)$ is metric space, then the distance from $p$ to $C$ is a continuous function. If we consider the boundary of $C,$ $d(p,C)$ attains a minimum in such set, but, what about the rest of $C?$

Is there another easier way to proof this?

Any kind of help is thanked in advanced

Comment: Pick $q$ in $C$ and consider only the points $p'$ in $C$ with $d(p,p') \leq  d(p,q)$.

Comment: Thanks to answer @CatalinZara. Let $A:=\{p^{'}\in C:d(p,p^{'})\leq  d(p,q)\}$ where $q\in C$ and $p\in M$ fixed point. Such set is closed because of continuity of Riemannian metric, and is bounded because $d(p,q)$ is fixed positive number with $q$ fixed, right? Then $A$ is compact for Hopf-Rinow and we have the case mentioned above. But why this is enogh to finish the proof?

Comment: Or I don't understand your idea @CatalinZara?

Comment: @Squird37 Where did you find the statement to be proved? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in [the comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2801316/complete-riemannian-manifold-m-c-closed-subset-of-m-then-for-p-in-m-th#comment5775549_2801316), one can consider the

$$ C_R = C\cap B_R(p).$$

For $R$ large enough, $C_R$ is nonempty. Since $M$ is complete, the Hopf-Rinow theorem implies that $B_R(p)$ (and thus $C_R$) is compact. Thus there is $p' \in C_R$ so that 
$$ d(p,p') = \inf_{s\in C_R} d(p,s).$$

Since $d(p, p')\le R$, we also have

$$ d(p,p') = \inf_{s\in C} d(p,s).$$

Comment: Thanks @JohnMa. Now everything is clear.